# How to Start At Selected Index in Carousel View Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm trying to implement a carousel view that, when a user selects an image from a list, the Carousel View shows that image from the selected index on start.

My Attempt:

In my code I'm setting the Position field to the selected index, but its not working for me. I also don't see any other fields associated with CarouselView that would move to a selected index from an index number or matching object (unless I missed something).

Heres my code so far:

```
public partial class ImagePreview : ContentPage
    {
        int index; 
        public ImagePreview(Picture photo, int i)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.index = i;
            photo_carousel.Position = index;
            photo_carousel.ItemsSource = App.rug.photos;
        }
    }
```

Heres the backend:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <cv:CarouselView  x:Name="photo_carousel">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                  <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
                    <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Length}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          </cv:CarouselView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Xamarin Studio. This is a forms project, but the carousel is for the iOS implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the [Xamarin.Forms Carousel View](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView) on `iOS` where it does not scroll to the position on initial load. This is a bug in the library Xamarin have provided.

The pull request which fixes this can be found here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/pull/9

They have [planned](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1) to make the `CarouselView` stable by February 2017:

> **CarouselView v1 Stable** - Feature CarouselView was introduced at
>   Xamarin Evolve 2016 and has been in prerelease ever since. v1 brings
>   stability and performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
photo_carousel.Position = index;
photo_carousel.ItemsSource = App.rug.photos;
```

Try with:

```
photo_carousel.ItemsSource = App.rug.photos;
photo_carousel.Position = index;
```

Every time you set the ItemSource, Position will be set to default value of 0